# HomeController not changing welcome.blade.php when I edit?

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to add a table in resources\views\welcome.blade.php. So I add the html table code there and it works.
Then I try to edit app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php to see a vardump in welcome.blade.php but nothing shows there, continue only my table.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm new using laravel.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\ModelHome;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->objUser=new User();
        $this->objBook=new ModelFuncionarios();
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->objUser);
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Homecontroller doesn't use `welcome.blade.php` but `home.blade.php`. `dd(...)` is short for "dump & die" - it dumps the information and stops script execution. Also, you need to be logged in/auth'd to use HomeController, probably redirected you to `welcome.blade.php` before executing your `index` method

Comment: @brombeer - just answer :)

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 Was doing it, had to feed my cat first! ;) Thx

Answer (score 2):

Your Homecontroller doesn't use `welcome.blade.php` but `home.blade.php`. `dd(...)` is short for "dump & die" - it dumps the information and stops script execution.

Also, you need to be logged in/auth'd to use `HomeController`, you are redirected to `welcome.blade.php` before executing your `index` method.

Edit: if you want to "var_dump" information and *not* stop script execution but continue to show the view you can use `dump()` instead of `dd()`

Answer (score 0):

When you do dd() the view will not load as this function ends the execution of the script.

Have a look here: [laravel 8 dd function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd)